# Interesting Ordinary Differential Equation Problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

consider the DE

$y'=\alpha x,x>0$

Where $\alpha$ is a constant. Show that :

1) if $\phi(x)$ is any solution and $\psi(x)=\phi(x)e^{-\alpha x}$ then $\psi(x)$ is a constant.

2) if $\alpha<0$, then every solution tends to zero as $x \rightarrow 0$

I tried the normal method of first solving the given ODE to find its solution and considering it to be $\phi(x)$, i found $\psi(x)$, tried differentiating it to show that its constant. but didn't work out.

Comment: Did you write the ODE correctly?

Comment: Typo, you want $\alpha y$, not $\alpha x$.

Comment: the question says $\alpha x$, by the way, is my approach correct ?

Comment: If it is $\alpha x$, then the solution is $y = (1/2)x^2 + c$ as opposed to if it is $y = \alpha y$, then $y(x) = c_1 e^{\alpha x}$. Problem looks wrong.

Comment: @user : the question reads $\alpha x$ but people here are of the view it should be something else. do you care to answer ?

Comment: @Amzoti : that is exactly how far i reached :)

Comment: @AmanMittal: Well, there is no way that parts 1 and 2 are going to work when the problem statement is incorrect. Regards

Comment: @Amzoti : May be you are right . Thanks, Regards

Comment: I would assume what Andre and I wrote and then everything makes sense and works. Clear?

Comment: Yes its quite clear now. Thanks

Comment: There is good reason to proceed as follows. Let $\phi(x)$ be a solution. Consider $\phi(x)e^{-\alpha x}$. Differentiate, then use $y'=\alpha y$ to show the derivative is $0$. Thus the function we just differentiated is constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with the question statement. First the equation should be 
$$
y' = \alpha \color{red}{y}.\tag{1}
$$
Secondly it should be concerning with the limiting behavior of $y$ namely 
$$
y\to 0\text{ when } x\to \color{red}{+\infty}.\tag{2}
$$

Hints:

1. If $\psi(x)$ is a constant, then 
   $$
   \psi'(x) = \phi'(x)e^{-\alpha x}+ \phi(x)(-\alpha e^{-\alpha x})
   $$
   must be zero, is this true if $\phi(x)$ solves (1)?
2. The solution to (1) is $y = y(0)e^{\alpha x}$, where $y(0)$ is the initial value you assigned, take any real number $a = y(0)$, is (2) true?